# Next vs the next (year, month, week)

Tags: grammar, articles

I have read various opinions on this subject, and my English professor told me that:

When the definite article is used, it indicates the period itself, like:

> I will do it in the next week

= in the seven days from now (might be from Tuesday till Tuesday).

Next year - 2019. In the next year: in 12 months from now, so in April 2019.

> I will meet you next week.  //next week, might be tomorrow if today is Saturday
>    I will meet you in the next week. //in the next 7 days

Is that correct?

Comment: You are _much_ more likely to see "**within a week**" than "in the next week".

Comment: I think the most common distinction is that unless there's a preposition (as in *He will do it **during** the next week*) we don't include the article when ***next** [time-period]* is a reference relative to ***now** = time of utterance*. When it's relative to some other "narrative time", such as *He arrived **the** next day,* we do include the article.

Comment: @FumbleFingers He will do it next year (any time in 2019), He will do it in the next year (from now till April 2019), isn't that so?

Comment: Yes. But that distinction is as much a matter of whether you include ***in*** as whether you include ***the***. Take *He promised he'd do it **the** [very] next week,* for example. By default I'd assume this refers to the calendar week *starting immediately after* the one in which he made the promise (i.e. - if that was on a Monday he could still keep his promise even if he didn't do it until 13 days later). But if we included ***in*** there, he'd have to deliver on his promise within 7 days of making it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, that was helpful. With "the last" I think it is easier - The prices have increased in the last month // implies again I would say 30 days, not a calendar month.

Comment: Note that you can include the article only *(He promised he'd do it **the** next week)* or preposition + article *(He promised he'd do it **in the** next week)*, but preposition only *(He promised he'd do it **in** next week)* strikes me as just plain ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, both possibilities are vague. I would argue that they are equally vague. There are no significant differences between using "next" and "in the next" **if you want the time frame to be unclear**.

If, however, you are concerned because you want the time frame to be more defined, it might be helpful for you to consider ways to add specificity. For example,

> I will meet you one week from today.

For more great examples, see this post: ["In the next two weeks" vs. "next two weeks"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58836/in-the-next-two-weeks-vs-next-two-weeks)