# How to say date relative to an event in the past from present perspective?

Tags: past-tense, dates

I know that *tomorrow* is *the day after that* or *the next day* and *last night* is *the night before* and so on. However, I am not sure about some other dates such as **next Monday**, **this week** and specifically **4 weeks from next Monday**.

Comment: Related: ["Next" vs "in the next" for dates](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163678/next-vs-the-next-year-month-week).

Comment: Do  you mean "day" rather than date? Also, you say an event i**n the past in your question** and then **you switch to future  in your text**. Kindly clarify what you mean. To speak today about past days: Yesterday, two days ago, three days ago,etc.; last Monday, two Mondays ago; last month, two months ago. etc.

Answer (score 2):

We can shift from the future in the present to the future in the past, when talking about dates, by substituting 'the following' for 'next', and 'that' for 'this':

Next Monday: the following Monday.

This week: that week.

Four weeks from next Monday: four weeks from the following Monday.

Next year: [during/in] the following year.

Comment: Can we use “‘the’ next Monday” instead of “the following Monday”?

Comment: @user67265 yes, "the next Monday" still works for shifting from the past.

Comment: @PaulDexter the significance is the word “the”, right?